# SQL loop insert using declared table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a declared table which has a lot of data in it... I get the data by doing a select query on my `InventoryLogs`.. now, what I want is to insert this data on another table called `MonthlySalesHistoryDetail`... However I don't know how to get the values of my declared table...

this is a stored procedure:

```
    Alter Procedure InsertMonthlySalesHistoryEndDate
    @CurrentDate date,
    @CreatedByID int,
    @LastInsertID int

    as

    Declare @details table
    (
        RowID int identity(1,1) primary key,
        MonthlySalesHistoryID int,
        ItemID int,
        MeasurementUnitID int,
        QuantitySold numeric(18,4),
        QuantityReturned numeric(18,4),
        TotalSoldAmount numeric(18,4),
        TotalReturnedAmount numeric(18,4)
    )


    Insert Into @details
    (
        MonthlySalesHistoryID,
        ItemID,
        MeasurementUnitID,
        QuantitySold,
        QuantityReturned,
        TotalSoldAmount,
        TotalReturnedAmount
    )

    SELECT 
        @LastInsertID,
        il.ItemID, 
        il.MeasurementUnitID,
        SUM(il.Quantity) as QuantitySold,
        ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM InventoryLogs WHERE TransactionType = 15 AND CAST(InventoryLogDate as date) = @CurrentDate),0) as QuantityReturned,
        SUM(il.ComputedCost) as TotalSoldAmount,
        ISNULL((SELECT SUM(ComputedCost) FROM InventoryLogs WHERE TransactionType = 15 AND CAST(InventoryLogDate as date) = @CurrentDate),0) as TotalReturnedAmount
    FROM InventoryLogs il 
    WHERE il.TransactionType = 9 AND CAST(InventoryLogDate as date) = @CurrentDate
    GROUP BY il.ItemID, il.MeasurementUnitID


    declare @count int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @details)
    declare @counter int = 0

    WHILE(@count > @counter)
    BEGIN

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
        SELECT * FROM @details d Where d.RowID = @counter
        INSERT INTO MonthlySalesHistoryDetails
        (
            MonthlySalesHistoryID,
            ItemID, 
            MeasurementUnitID, 
            QuantitySold, 
            QuantityReturned, 
            TotalSoldAmount, 
            TotalReturnedAmount
        )
        VALUES
        (
           //I want to get the values of my 
           //SELECT * FROM @details d Where d.RowID = @counter here..
        )
    END
```

thanks in advance....

Comment: I already got it.... my bad.. I didn't know it was possible...

Comment: next question: why `@details` is still there? insert...select

Comment: @IvanStarostin what do you mean? `insert` there will get the data of the `select` and insert it..

Comment: If this is a full source code - you don't need an intermediate table variable. Try inserting directly to the destination table. Single statement: `insert into MonthlySalesHistoryDetails ... select ... from InventoryLogs ...`

Comment: @IvanStarostin I've tried to add it directly and it has  errors.


`Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Procedure InsertMonthlySalesHistoryEndDate, Line 0
Procedure or function InsertMonthlySalesHistoryEndDate has too many arguments specified.`

Comment: @IvanStarostin I see... I get it now.. it's much more simplier... thanks....

Comment: I'm afraid error message says nothing about insert statement. Your own answer shown below demonstrates correct approach of insert-select. Just replace `select` part with `select` part from `Insert Into @details...` statement persisted in your question. That's it.

Comment: @IvanStarostin yeah, I got your idea.... I don't need the `variable tabe`.... thanks sir you are a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that it was possible to do this insert... I thought it was only good for `declared table`

```
INSERT INTO MonthlySalesHistoryDetails
        (
            MonthlySalesHistoryID,
            ItemID,
            MeasurementUnitID,
            QuantitySold,
            QuantityReturned,
            TotalSoldAmount,
            TotalReturnedAmount
        )
        SELECT 
               d.MonthlySalesHistoryID, 
               d.ItemID,
               d.MeasurementUnitID,
               d.QuantitySold,
               d.QuantityReturned,
               d.TotalSoldAmount,
               d.TotalReturnedAmount
        FROM @details d Where d.RowID = @counter
```